# PHP - Run script/function/class continuously and update variables (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I need something specific and i have no idea how to approach it.

I need to run a script/class/function continuously with start/stop button in my browser and update my views accordingly.

The script calls an API every minute and updates the variable in the class.

I made a basic Controller with a displayPage() method that returns the view with $data.

Inside the controller , i called the class that is supposed to run continuously . It has global variables. I was thinking of adding a while(true) loop function which does not return anything but instead updates the variable.

Controller :

```
$c = new Folder\TestClass();

$c->start();

$x = $c->variable1value;

return view('testpage',$x);
```

**I'm not sure if the above will work or if there is a better way to do it . Any advise would be much appreciated.**

Now , if the above works :

How do i update my view ?

I was thinking of making an update() function in the controller and call it using javascript every minute . I don;t want to reload the whole page however , just the view i.e : $x value , reinitialize graphs etc...

Comment: Why would anything need to run “continuously” here? What exactly do you need to update, based on what? Please first of all properly describe what you actually want to _achieve_ here.

Comment: it will not work .. it will reach time limit for the sever to respond ..

Comment: what you can do is have a front end ajax call every now and then .. like for every 10secs you will run that class ..

Comment: @CBroe - The script calls an API every minute and updates the variable in the class.

Comment: Sounds like something you should rather do via a cron job.

Comment: @CBroe - how do i keep track of the class/variable then ?

Comment: cron for this will not work. @Sam.tuver try [socketsIO](https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io) or [socketo](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: Store the data in a file or a database …?